# Cannot read property 'first' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm currently making a discord bot so whenever someone types `!true @USER [Location]` it will DM the @USER a message, add a role and then nickname the user to [Location] with the following code :

```
const mention = message.mentions.members.first();

msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

if (msg.startsWith(prefix)){
if(message.channel.id === '12345'){

    if (msg.startsWith (prefix + "true")){
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")) return message.reply("You have no permission!");
        if (mention == null) { return; }
        let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(2);
        if ((mention.displayName + " " + args.join(" ")).length > 32) return message.channel.send("The nickname exceeds 32 characters")
        if(mention.roles.cache.has('1234567890')){
        message.reply("User is already accepted.")
        } else {
        mention.roles.add('1234567890').then(() => mention.setNickname(mention.displayName+" "+args.join('  ')))
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('handle error here: ', e.message)
        })            
     }
}}}
```

However, most of the time it will return with `Cannot read property 'first' of null` and it won't change the user's nickname (only roles and DM). Is there anything wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mention = message.mentions.members.first();
```

In the above code, `message.mentions.members` is null so you can't access a property (here `first`) in a null object.

The culprit is probably somewhere you set `members` property, not the code you provided here. do some debugging and `console.log` and you'll fix the issue.

Comment: @Prism, it's not an error. it is ```null```. It's very likely that there are scenarios in which ```message.mentions.members``` is null. if you want us to help in that regard, I suggest you to edit this post with your code, or better, resolve this question and ask another one.

Answer (score 0):

You got error because you can`t get `first` of null. Better check mention in a command, like this.

```js
if (msg.startsWith(prefix)) {
    if (message.channel.id === '12345') {
        if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'true')) {
            if (args.length < 0) return message.reply('PLS mention a member or write his ID');
            const mention = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
            if (!mention) return message.reply('Can`t find a member');
            msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
            if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_NICKNAMES')) return message.reply('You have no permission!');
            if (mention == null) {
                return;
            }
            let args = message.content.split(' ').slice(2);
            if ((mention.displayName + ' ' + args.join(' ')).length > 32) return message.channel.send('The nickname exceeds 32 characters');
            if (mention.roles.cache.has('1234567890')) {
                message.reply('User is already accepted.');
            } else {
                mention.roles
                    .add('1234567890')
                    .then(() => mention.setNickname(mention.displayName + ' ' + args.join('  ')))
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log('handle error here: ', e.message);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```